# Is there a length limit to field values in mongo queries?

Tags: mongodb

I've got a single document in a collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("508836afea5cea2ccec11a0d"),
  created_at: 1348657869.204,
  name: "Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"
}
```

I can find it with

```
find({"created_at":1348657869.204})
```

but

```
find({"name":"Abcd...<actual name here>...uvwx"})
```

returns no results.  Is there a length limit to the field in the query?

Comment: Works for me, I've tested it this way: 1. Add your document to script file as an argument for db.test.insert(); 2. Create another script file, that does print(db.test.find( <json as query with name> ).count()) - and it prints 1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The limit you are encountering is the maximum line buffer size in the `mongo` shell, which is [4096 bytes](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/linenoise.cpp#L143) as at MongoDB 2.2.1.  If you try pasting your example in the `mongo` shell you should notice that you cannot add any characters beyond the line limit.

If you execute this query from a [language driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) you will not have this issue.

You could also workaround this in the `mongo` shell by loading the query from a JavaScript file specified on the command line:

```
 mongo longname.js
```

Or by creating a long string in the `mongo` shell programmatically:

```
// Longname will be 5000 characters
var longname = '';
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    longname += 'Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx ';
}

db.foo.insert({
  _id: ObjectId("508836afea5cea2ccec11a0d"),
  created_at: 1348657869.204,
  name: longname
});

printjson(db.foo.findOne({name: longname}))
```

Comment: Wow, and they bake it into the binary as a preprocessor directive .... fantastic! https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/linenoise.cpp#L141 <-- line number at the time of writing