# How to increase the limit of a line in the Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

When I am passing a long line with multiple inserts in mongo shell I get unclear errors:

```
2020-07-13T15:59:21.264+0100 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']' :
@(shell):1:0
```

I figured out it is due to the line buffer length.

How can I make it longer?

Comment: More likely you typoed something somewhere.

Comment: Is this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606646/insert-large-record-into-mongodb-using-mongo-shell/61609037#61609037

Comment: Add the command here

Comment: It is `db.knodes.insertMany([ /* ... */])` with about 20 objects, all together getting over 10K characters

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a hard limit to the Mongo shell line lengths:

[Shell @ MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#shell)

> The mongo shell prompt has a limit of 4095 codepoints for each line. If you enter a line with more than 4095 codepoints, the shell will truncate it.

Here are [more details](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-8362)

and the exact limit origin of[**`4095 codepoints`**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/e5e2ecb49da979c5cc3534ae3cb76212a72e3986/src/mongo/shell/linenoise.cpp#L141)

Apparently, without a way to configure and extend it.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's an option for you, a simple way around this limitation is to just divide your statement into multiple lines.

As an example, if your statement looks like this:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "foo": {
      "$in": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, (...), 2000, 2001, 2002] // line longer than supported
    }
  }
}])
```

You can divide the long line into smaller chunks so that each line is no longer than the limit:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "foo": {
      "$in": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, (...), // line shorter than limit
        2000, 2001, 2002]
    }
  }
}])
```